# Delay with remapped q

Tags: key-bindings, error

I've remapped q to :bp, but to get an instant response, I have to press it twice. Otherwise there's a two second delay. What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

```
function! NetrwMapping()
  noremap <buffer> q :bp<CR>
endfunction
```

Comment: I tried `:nmap q :bp<CR>` and that worked without a delay for me. Although if you've mapped something else to q<some other key>, that might be causing the delay. You can check this by trying `:nmap q` and see what the output is.

Comment: Please provide the *exact* command you used to remap it, otherwise, nobody can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because Vim waits to see if you want to do `q<letter>` to start recording a macro (there are a couple other things too like `q:`).
You can use the `tm` option to change the amount it waits(will apply to all maps), or remap it to another unused letter.